# How to access a variable in child class from an obj in parent class object in systemverilog

Tags: oop, system-verilog

So I want to modify a variable which is not directly in parent class but is in a class which is instantiated in parent class. for eg.

```
class cfg;

    int a  

endclass

class parent;

    cfg cfg1

endclass
class child extends parent;

    <how to change variable "a" here which is declared in cfg?>

endclass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is using the terms *parent* and *child* with respect to *inheritance*. Those terms imply two separate objects. What you have is a *base* class type and an *derived* class type. When constructing a derived class object, you have access to everything in the base class as if it were all in the same class.

```
class cfg;

    int a  

endclass

class base;

    cfg cfg1

endclass
class derived extends base;

    //<how to change variable "a" here which is declared in cfg?>
    //Answer: Just use cfg1.a
endclass
```